# Generation of unique normalized and weight value from a set with different number of elements

Tags: normal-distribution

I am researching about data mining and my math skills are weak. Therefore, I need the help of people who understand better than I on this subject.

To generate a specific formula for my research, I need to define some steps, and for this, I need to take a group of elements, specifically, three elements and have as return a single normalized value.

For example:

*f1 = (105, 312, 75)*. These elements can range from zero to values greater than one million.

I tried to use *fnorm = (X - min(X)) / (max(X) - min(X))* and calculated the arithmetic mean for the group of elements, but the representation of the result does not agree with what I would like.

Comparing two sets of these elements, for example:

*f1 = (105, 312, 75)*

*f2 = (22, 23, 1)*

When I apply *fnorm* and the arithmetic mean of the values, I get the final result -> *f1 = 0.3755* and *f2 = 0.65*.

These results are not complete for me, because even though they are normalized, the elements of *f1* are greater than *f2*. Therefore, I need *f1* to be more representative, have greater weight than *f2*. Another point is that if there is a value 0 within the group, it cannot zero the whole result the other different elements of zero are relevant to the outcome.

I hope I explained it correctly but if there's any confusion please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have many vectors that need to be comparable, or just two at a time? 

Do you have a single data set of vectors, or can you get new new data which should also be comparable with the old data?

Comment: Yes, I have many vectors that need to be comparable, as it comes to similarity, just two at a time. The vector data set refers to values assigned to users. If user data changes, then those set values will be updated. Moreover, these new data will now be compared to all other users.

Comment: @Eff, I thought of using weighted mean, but I need to set weights for the elements. For me, all elements have equal weights, returning to be a simple arithmetic mean. If I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get your desired result if you normalize a vector with respect to itself, consider e.g. the vectors:
\begin{align}
f_1&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c
\end{bmatrix}\\
f_2&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a+100&b+100&c+100
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
These will get the same scores, whereas you would want the second to score higher.

The way to correct this is to normalize with respect to the vector with the highest possible values. Consider any vector $\mathbf x = [x_1,x_2,x_3]$, then define the average as
$$\text{avg}(\mathbf x) = \frac13\sum\limits_{k=1}^3 x_k, $$

i.e. simply the arithmetic mean. This makes sense, as you say, when each element in the vector has the same weight. Otherwise use a weighted mean.

Consider now a dataset of many vectors $\mathbf x^{(i)}$, where the superscript refers to the vector number $i$, e.g. $\mathbf x^{(5)}$ is the fifth vector in your database. Then you have to normalize with respect to the one with the highest average, i.e. you first want to find
$$M = \max\limits_i\big\{\text{avg}\big(\mathbf x^{(i)}\big)\big\}.$$

Finding the maximum is not difficult, it does not need some big optimization problem. It simply boils down to calculating $\text{avg}(\mathbf x^{(i)})$ for all $i$ and simply choosing the largest.

Now we wish to calculate the normalized norm. It is simply given by
$$\|\mathbf x^{(i)}\| = \frac{\text{avg}\big(\mathbf x^{(i)}\big)}{M}.$$

**Remarks.** In this case you will always have the value of $1$ for the vector with the largest mean.

Furthermore, using this method may require you to recalculate the norm of every element once you get new data. More precisely, if you ever get a vector with larger mean than the previous largest. This can be avoided if you a priori know a maximum possible value of the arithmetic mean, in which case you simply use that value instead of $M$ (and then only the maximum possible vector would have the normalized value of $1$).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Eff. It seems to me to be a good solution and thank you for your attention. I will test in my research and see how the results are. Regards.

Comment: @ThacianaGOCerqueira No problem! Feel free to report back if it does/does not work.